# search for a specific property in array of objects and return boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

lets say i have an array of objects

```
    let arr = [
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "george",
    age: 55
  }
];
```

and an object

```
  let obj = {
    name: "bill",
    age: 55
  }
```

and i want to search all `arr` objects to find anyone with the same age as `obj.age` and return a boolean depending whether it includes a same property or not.

i can obviously do :

```
let find = arr.filter(i => i.age === obj.age);
let bool = find.length > 0 && true;
```

but is there a way to call a method (lodash,plain js or whatever) to just get this by design like `method(arr,obj.age) //returns true` ?

```js
let arr = [
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "george",
    age: 55
  }
];

let obj = {
  name: "bill",
  age: 55
}

let find = arr.filter(i => i.age === obj.age);
let bool = find.length > 0 && true;

console.log(bool)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `some`. So basically it will return a boolean value if any of the object property in array matches the required value

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "john",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "george",
    age: 55
  }
];
let obj = {
  name: "bill",
  age: 55
}

const val = arr.some(item => item.age === obj.age);
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it in two ways. we can use the **some** function and get the boolean directly or by **find** function, we can convert it to a boolean using !! operator.

```
let arr = [{
    name: "john",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "george",
    age: 55
  }
];
let obj = {
  name: "bill",
  age: 55
}

const val1 = arr.some(item => item.age === obj.age);
console.log(val1)
const val2 = !!arr.find(item => item.age === obj.age);
console.log(val2)
```